# How to add toggle button on google map api v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I found library: [geometrycontrols](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geometrycontrols/examples/test.html) that is written to api v2 and allows adding buttons. How to make a toggle button to add a marker in the api v3? I have initiated map etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add an arbitrary structured `<div>` to the map:

```
var control = document.createElement('div');
```

You add a listener to this control or to its children, e.g.:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(control, 'click', function() {...});
```

You position the control on the map:

```
control.index = 1;   
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(control);
```

For details, see:

[Custom Controls](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#CustomControls)

[Example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom.html)

Comment: When I use this in combination with a toggling jQuery element, the custom control disappears after the jQuery/jqlite element is shown again. Only appears again if I zoom. No work around so far.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to add any listener to the map at all.  Just add it to the HTML element(s) in your custom control.

You certainly want to add your custom logos and buttons and copyrights to Google Maps via custom controls.  Otherwise, they will likely not render properly especially on mobile devices.

I found the official [Google Maps JavaScript API Custom Control example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomExample) to be rather complicated and I can never remember the position options.  So, I created a [tiny 1.72 KB add-on JS on GitHub](https://github.com/rhroyston/control-js) library called CONTROL-JS that enables you to simply create your custom content as a string, e.g., `var html = "<h1>Hi</h1>"` then pass it to an object called `control` where every position is a method (IDE intellisense reminds you of the possible positions).

So, in your case, unsing CONTROL-JS just do

```
var html = '<p id="control-text"> Zoom </p>'

//Global method that is fired when the API is loaded and ready
function initMap () {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    //intelleSense/Auto-complete works on IDE's
    control.topCenter.add(html);
};
```

[image]

```js
/*
control.js v0.1 - Add custom controls to Google Maps with ease
Created by Ron Royston, www.rack.pub
https://github.com/rhroyston/control
License: MIT
control.topCenter.add.(html)
*/
var control=function(){function o(o){this.add=function(T){var t=document.createElement("div");if(t.innerHTML=T,o)switch(o){case"TOP_CENTER":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(t);break;case"TOP_LEFT":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(t);break;case"TOP_RIGHT":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(t);break;case"LEFT_TOP":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push(t);break;case"RIGHT_TOP":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(t);break;case"LEFT_CENTER":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER].push(t);break;case"RIGHT_CENTER":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER].push(t);break;case"LEFT_BOTTOM":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM].push(t);break;case"RIGHT_BOTTOM":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(t);break;case"BOTTOM_CENTER":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER].push(t);break;case"BOTTOM_LEFT":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT].push(t);break;case"BOTTOM_RIGHT":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT].push(t)}else console.log("err")}}var T={};return T.topCenter=new o("TOP_CENTER"),T.topLeft=new o("TOP_LEFT"),T.topRight=new o("TOP_RIGHT"),T.leftTop=new o("LEFT_TOP"),T.rightTop=new o("RIGHT_TOP"),T.leftCenter=new o("LEFT_CENTER"),T.rightCenter=new o("RIGHT_CENTER"),T.leftBottom=new o("LEFT_BOTTOM"),T.rightBottom=new o("RIGHT_BOTTOM"),T.bottomCenter=new o("BOTTOM_CENTER"),T.bottomLeft=new o("BOTTOM_LEFT"),T.bottomRight=new o("BOTTOM_RIGHT"),T}();
```